# Oracle database operations running after stopping the application server

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, websphere-8

When the stored procedures are running in my application server I have stopped my application server. After stopping my application server, the stored procedures are still continued running in my oracle 11g database. My application server is running in Web application sphere 8.5.5. All the database operations should have been cancelled when the application server stopped. How can I stop the database operations which are running when the application server is stopped.

My oracle database has been moved to new ODA. After moving to new ODA only I am facing this problem. Still the old ODA is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill database sessions.

First identify session with query:

```
SELECT s.inst_id,
   s.sid,
   s.serial#,
   p.spid,
   s.username,
   s.program
FROM   gv$session s
   JOIN gv$process p ON p.addr = s.paddr AND p.inst_id = s.inst_id
WHERE  s.type != 'BACKGROUND';
```

Then kill it for proper sid and serial:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

For more info look at: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions.php